# Tensorflow: how can I detect handwriting numbers in an image if I have a trained MNIST model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have trained a model using MNIST dataset by the example code from
https://keras.io/examples/vision/mnist_convnet/

I have an image containing several handwriting numbers and other characters, in different sizes, and in different colors.

I want to detect the  handwriting numbers (0-9) using the trained model, and draw a bound rectangle around each number.

Is it possible? any advice is appreciated.
My environment: tensorflow 2.7 + python 3. Keras is used.

Comment: You will need to build an object detector. Here's a [link to a good tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/06/22/turning-any-cnn-image-classifier-into-an-object-detector-with-keras-tensorflow-and-opencv/) on the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your output layer looks like this:
`(Dense) (None, 10) 16010`
And you defined your classes with:
`num_classes = 10`

you use
`pred = model.predict(image)` where image is your image.

Be aware that your image needs the shape = (28, 28, 1)
so its x value is 28, y value is 28  and the color channel is 1 = (Grayscale).
You need to convert your image to a numpy array.

It will give you an array where the highest number is the outcome of your digit.

Like: [0.2, 0.4, 0.9, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.6, 0.2]

So in this case the number would be a 2

If you really want to draw a box around it, you need an object detector which is way more complex and time consuming.

Comment: is it ok to pass my image to the model? my image contains many numbers and other characters, not a single number.

Comment: No, the only way to handle this, is to scan over the image, with a matrix of 28 by 28, but if you do this, the result is unreliable and all the problems, you will encounter are already solved by an object detector.
What you can try is, using image processing with e.g. opencv to cluster the numbers  and than pass the frame to the model.